# How this author made the equalizer effect inside text?

Tags: jquery, text, css, canvas, effect

http://www.chris-wang.com/

If you hover over the textual navigation words on this page, you'll see it changes color from left to right, inside the text. I can't figure out how this guy did that, or even what technology he used to do it.

Is he using canvas to do it? Does anyone know how he did this effect? The text isn't an image, it's selectable text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's javascript with jquery:

```
function onOver(){
        //var txtwidth = $(this).document.getElementsByClassName("nav_over").clientWidth;
        //var txtwidth = $(this).children(".nav_over").offsetWidth;
        var txtWidth = $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_base").width();
        //var txtWidth = document.getElementByClass("nav_base").offsetWidth
        //var txtWidth = $(document).width();
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").stop();
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").animate({
            width:txtWidth
        }, speed,"easeOutExpo");
    };
function onOut(){
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").stop();
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, speed,"easeOutExpo");
};
```

Essentially just 2 divs with the same text but two different colors.  When moused over, the orange one is animated to cover over the white one.

Answer (score 0):

He's using jQuery to make that effect. Specifically:

```
$(".nav_button").mouseover(onOver);
$(".nav_button").mouseout(onOut);
```

and:

```
function onOver(){
        //var txtwidth = $(this).document.getElementsByClassName("nav_over").clientWidth;
        //var txtwidth = $(this).children(".nav_over").offsetWidth;
        var txtWidth = $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_base").width();
        //var txtWidth = document.getElementByClass("nav_base").offsetWidth
        //var txtWidth = $(document).width();
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").stop();
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").animate({
            width:txtWidth
        }, speed,"easeOutExpo");
    };
function onOut(){
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").stop();
        $(this).children(".project_header").children(".nav_btn").children(".nav_overlay").animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, speed,"easeOutExpo");
```